# Resize font size automatically to fill bounding box

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an area text box, I would like the behaviour that the font size is automatically adjusted depending on the width or height of the bounding box. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look into scripting...

or.. simply use the **Free Transform Tool** with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key held down to scale the type along with its bounding box.